# Writing text file invalid syntax

Tags: python, syntax, text-files

Can somebody tell me why I keep getting an error: `invalid syntax`. I can't figure this, the error is on line 6 and is 'reorder_file':

```
import sqlite3
product_db = sqlite3.connect("G://Computing\\Reorder_file.db")
c = product_db.cursor()
c.execute("DROP TABLE if exists Reorder_file.db")
c.execute("CREATE TABLE reorder_file(GTIN8_Product_Code text,            Product_Description text, Cost float, Stock integer, Reorder_Level integer, Target_Level integer)"
reorder_file = open("reorder_file.txt", "w")
reorder_file .write("Reorder File")
reorder_file .write("GTIN8, Product Description, Price, Stock Level, Reorder Level, Target Level")
```

Comment: the error is occuring on "reorder_file" btw

Comment: You need to end the previous line with another )

Comment: im so dumb thank you @mauve

Answer (score 0):

Remove the spaces between **reorder_file** and **.write**.

I ran the following and didn't get any errors:

```
reorder_file = open("reorder_file.txt", "w")
reorder_file.write("Reorder File")
reorder_file.write("GTIN8, Product Description, Price, Stock Level, Reorder Level, Target Level")
```

Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: not quite the error is on the first line when i attempt to open the file

Comment: check the line before it. Frequently an error will pretend it's on the next line.

Comment: @mauve can you check the previous lines i have updated the code block

Comment: It looks like one the line before it you have:

Comment: c.execute("CREATE TABLE ...stuf stuff)"

Comment: Try putting that quote before the parentheses and running. (Sorry for the 3 comments. I keep forgetting to hit shift before I hit enter.)

Your code should look like:

c.execute(CREATE TABLE... stuff stuff...")